# How many database should replicate (publisher, distributor, subscriber) in sitecore 9.0?

Tags: c#, database, sitecore, database-replication

We have Sitecore 9.0 production server which has two MSSQL database. Environment is setup with AWS (VM) on premises MSSQL database. We want to replicate all database from one sql server (master,core,shared,reporting etc..) to another sql server.

How to replicated AWS VM on premises sitecore 9.0 databases?

check this link
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/scale-databases.html

[image]

Comment: If you are unsure about how to manage and configure MSSQL, Why not using a RDS instance?.

Comment: Hello Jan, Actually this configuration is provided by client. They are specific with this only. We don't have option.

Comment: is the web and xConnect also in that one sql server?

Answer (score 0):

For Sitecore there should be only 1 master database. Also there should be only 1 CM Server active (exception are possible with config in the picture it is named cold so that looks good).

To stay close to the drawing which is not necessarily the best solution. Alternative options are certainly possible especially for the web databases. An option is to have a High Availability database, SQL server always on. See [Sitecore Configure SQL server always on](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/configure-sql-server-always-on.html) and see [Support for SQL Server scaling features](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/423602) for the other options if data loss or long recovery time is allowed.

SQL server always on is basically the Supported by Sitecore option on VM's. For Database Mirroring: This feature will be removed from Microsoft SQL Server in the future. It is recommended to use AlwaysOn Availability Groups instead.

Comment: Hello Jan, We will create second Web database. Let me discuss with my team and get back to you. Thanks for answer it will help us lot.